# Hide button when I finish my onclick show div

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide

I,m an absolute begginner with jquery. I´m using google to learn but I don't find how to solve this for sure easy question.

I´m showing divs consecutively whith a button but I would like to hide the show button when there are no more divs to show.

This is the code:

```
$('#show').on('click', function() {
    if (index + 1 > max) {
        // Here, I suppose, I need to hide the button
    } else {
        if (index < max - 1) {
            index++;
            $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
        }
```

And here you can see the example

http://jsfiddle.net/vcARq/

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to do this on complete running the function like this

```
var index = -1;
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function() {
        if (index < max - 1) {
            index++;
            $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
        }
}, function () {
$(this).hide();
});
```

That should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking if the last div is displayed each time the button is clicked. So, if the last div is displayed, it hides the button. Here's the code:

```
    var index = -1;
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function() {
    if (index + 1 > max) {
        // Do Nothing
    } else {
        if (index < max - 1) {
            index++;
            $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
        }


    }
    if ($('div.hidden:last').css('display') != 'none'){
     $('#show').hide()   ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you iterate the index, check the value minus `2` inside of the callback function for `.show()`. This will result in the expected behavior. The reason it's `-2` is because you started your offset at `-1` instead of `0`.

```
var index = -1
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (index < max) {
        index++;
        $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show(0, function () {
            if (index > max - 2) {
                $this.hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2svT9/)

Answer (score 0):

I case of your condition (clicked max times) just call .hide().
Here my simple proposal:

```
var index = -1;
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function() {
    if (--max<=0) {          //condition
        $('#show').hide();   //hide button
    } 
    index++;
    $('.container > div:eq(' + index + ')').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcARq/8/

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to jquery I really appreciate your work, bravo and nice attempt your code is almost near to what u want:

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcARq/9/)

and u need this code:

```
var index = 0;
var max = $('.container > div').length;
$('#show').on('click', function() {
        if (index < max ) {

       $('.container > div:eq(' + index+')').show();
                index++;
             if (index >= max ) 
                 $(this).hide();
        }   
});
```

Comment: Awasome!! Brilliantly solved and I understand it. Thanks a lot and  I`ll go on studying